# IIS 6.1 with window authentication keep asking for login

Tags: iis, iis-6

I have an application running on IIS 6.1 with .NET framework 2.

At IIS's Authentication, I had disabled Anonymous Authentication and enabled Windows Authentication (with NTLM on top). Because this application is for internal use only and the authentication will be based on user's NT account from AD.

When I tried to launch the application, everything is ok. But when I wanted to view other pages that are in the different folder with the default page, IIS keep asking the users to login. And when I tried to login with my NT account, it failed.

So I looked for the event log and found out the event ID is 5011, which is 'Web sites and Web applications depend on the availability of Internet Information Services (IIS) application pools. IIS application pools in turn depend on the Windows Process Activation Service (WAS). If WAS is not running or errors occur during the startup or shutdown of an application pool, Web sites and Web applications may not be available.'

I would like to let the user to browse the application without having the login window keep showing.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user's domain accounts have file level permissions (Read only is sufficient) to the website files.